# Connection between code coverage and defects per KLOC

Tags: testing, dependencies, test-coverage, measurement

Most of the articles I read state that the average number of defects per KLOC is 10-15 (most of the data seems to come from Microsoft). How does that number correlate with code coverage?

If my project has for example 80% code coverage would that translate into 5x less defects per KLOC ? If not, how would I focus testing to have meaningful code coverage - ie, code coverage that would correlate would decreased defects per KLOC ?

Comment: Code coverage does not automatically correlate with bug-free code. Your tests may cover some code but not all possible cases, or you may test and implement against a faulty understanding of the requirements (so even if your test says that your code behaves correctly, the user may say otherwise.) In addition, the number of defects per KLOC may differ wildly between programming languages, programming styles, complexity etc. I'd suggest that time is better spent fixing known bugs than hunting for unknown bugs (good code coverage notwithstanding).

Comment: Code coverage means nothing. Thought experiment: take a code base with 100% code coverage. Delete all the assertions from the tests. Now, you still have 100% code coverage but *you are testing absolutely nothing*. The *most* that code coverage can tell you is which parts of your code are *definitely not tested*.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for empirical results, which IIUC is off topic. In any case, studies of software bugs are usually terrible, with small N, underqualified subjects (usually students), and otherwise bad methodology.

Comment: `The most that code coverage can tell you is which parts of your code are definitely not tested.` and make you wonder *Why isn't tested?* If it's not worth it, then ok but if you can't say why, then is useless code. If you have fully tested your code and coverage is 50%, the other 50% is most likely garbage

Comment: Another thought to add to this: the tests are also code, and therefore also subject to having defects, probably at the same rate as the rest of the code!

Answer (score 1):

Code coverage and KLOC are irrelevant here. They are metrics that look nice on a spreadsheet and can be put on a graph to really make it look like you're doing something. But in reality, it does nothing to safeguard the quality of your end result.

For the continuation of this answer, I am going to sometimes use the analogy that bugs are criminals and your tests are cops. Code coverage relates to police car patrols, and KLOC relates to surface area.

> Most of the articles I read state that the average number of defects per KLOC is 10-15

Much like the metrics I talked about before, this seems like nothing but an irrelevant bit of trivia. What is the value of knowing this?
On average, faster cars are statistically more likely to be red than slower cars (this is a real fact). Therefore, if I paint my car red, it's going to be faster, right?

KLOC doesn't matter. What matters is how your application behaves. I can write the same application (i.e. same resulting behavior) in myriad ways, and I can easily vary the KLOC count by a factor of 10 or more.
Yeah, as I increase the amount of components in my codebase, there's more possible links that I could break. But bugs are disproportionately defined by the public behavior of the application, which in my example here doesn't change between the different ways of writing the same codebase.

I won't repeat the whole rhetoric here as it's been repeated in many places before, but I am going to summarize that **KLOC is an irrelevant metric of code quality.**

Trying to divine code quality via KLOC is like trying to decide if your town has a criminal element based on the town's surface area. It just doesn't quite make sense.

The further corollary here is that one would allegedly be able to lower the crime rate by reducing the surface area in which the same amount of people live.
Or, going back to software development, browse through [CodeGolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and try to convince me that if you wrote your code this way, it would be better because it would use less lines of code (or characters - same principle).

> How does that number correlate with code coverage?

The first question should be "does it?".

Since you did not link a source for your claim, your phrasing suggests that the average was calculated irrespective of the particular code coverage; so there's no meaningful conclusion to distill here.

> If my project has for example 80% code coverage would that translate into 5x less defects per KLOC ?

Even if I were to accept the assertion that KLOC and code coverage are meaningful metrics - which I still don't - your question is based on the assumption that any and all lines of code are equivalent in terms of likelihood to contain bugs.

Analogously, you are assuming the same population density everywhere, in order to assume that covering X% of the surface area with police patrols will decrease criminality by the same X%.

Criminals are people, and not every square mile/kilometer is going to contain the same amount of people, just like how not every 1000 lines of code is going to contain the same amount of meaningful behavior that is prone to bugs.

To use a US example, do you really think that there's as much crime happening in LA and New York compared to a rural region of the same combined surface area as LA and New York?

This immediately defeats the question, even assuming that KLOC and code coverage were meaningfully indicative metrics. And that's even assuming that you have perfect cops who never let any crime slip by; which is a further big assumption to add to the pile.

> If not, how would I focus testing to have meaningful code coverage - ie, code coverage that would correlate would decreased defects per KLOC ?

You've lost track of your goal. You are chasing the metric, rather than the real world benefit.

**You don't write tests to achieve high coverage.** Even if you believe in code coverage being a meaningful metric, it's not the solution in and of itself. It should not be the goal that you work towards, or that you use to argue that you've done your job well.

In other words, cops don't get a medal for patrolling everywhere. They get a medal for keeping crime figures low. How they lay out their patrols is a secondary consideration and contextual to particular areas.

Defects **per KLOC** is an irrelevant division of the amount of defects you have. What matters is how many bugs you have. The quality of your end product is measured based on what the end product does, not on the lines of code you wrote.
What's the end result here? Yeah we've got three massive breaking issues in the app, but it's okay because we've got 20KLOC more than our competitors?

In other words, three murders in a high-population-density block is exactly as problematic as three murders in a low density rural town with the same population figure.

If you should be using a metric here, it should be one of logical complexity (i.e. how many different behaviors your application should have), not one of line count required to achieve said complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this is a fuzzy answer for a fuzzy question.

What are your exact sources for those bugs/KLOC numbers?  You mention Microsoft - therefore it's likely that their testing code coverage is more than zero, and probably pretty high.  Maybe your sources mention this.

Things to also consider:

- Unit tests are also code, and therefore probably subject to similar bugs/KLOC numbers.
- Code may not be fully reproducible - e.g. it may have side-effects due to external state.  In other words, running the same code twice with the same input may not end up giving the same result - even in the unit tests.  This may confound the reported coverage value.
- The coverage calculation tool is likely to also have some bugs.
- People may use low-quality strategies to optimise for the metric (e.g. writing deliberately more verbose bugfree code to drop bugs/KLOC).

Therefore, as Flater mentions in his answer, all these numbers are, at best, "indicators".  You still need to know your company culture on writing code and tests, the operation of your tools, etc., there's no absolute intrinsic value in them.

They may tell you that your code is probably getting better or worse as the numbers change from an initial baseline, or instead it may be that devs are now optimizing for the metric rather than for actual code quality.  This is a real effect that can happen if for example you start linking developer evaluations to the value of those metrics.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite a few empirical research papers about the correlation between code coverage and the number of bugs, quality or cost efficiency.

The references [in this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324959836_Mythical_Unit_Test_Coverage) cite a range from no correlation at all (more tests does not mean less bugs) to strong correlation. [This review](https://gupea.ub.gu.se/bitstream/handle/2077/38588/gupea_2077_38588_1.pdf;jsessionid=C2B84384F66D5562F30433FA94EFCEB5?sequence=1) cites a few others claiming that code coverage contribution to quality flattens around 70%-90%.

Note that most of those papers only checked for correlation and not causation.

Practically it means that it is almost impossible to assess the number of bugs in your code, and that based on your 80% code coverage you need to keep the existing coverage level but look for other ways to improve the quality of your code.